# On epsilon-delta proofs for multi-variable limits

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

**Question**

Compute the following limit $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{y^2}{x-y}.$$

**My Answer**

I was taught to first show that the limit along any line and curve through the origin is $0$ which is true in this case, so I begin to suspect that the limit does exist and is equal to $0$.

Now, let $\epsilon > 0$. We want to find $\delta > 0$ such that, if $$0 < \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta,$$ then $$\left\lvert \frac{y^2}{x-y} - 0 \right\lvert < \epsilon.$$ In other words, if $$0 < \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta,$$ then $$\frac{y^2}{\lvert x-y \lvert} < \epsilon.$$

However, I am stuck here. How should I proceed with my epsilon-delta proof?

Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This limit does not exist.

Comment: Your "the limit along any line and curve through the origin is 0 which is true in this case" was wrong: take the curve $x=y+y^3.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limit does not exist. If you take $y=\frac 1 n$ and $x=\frac  1 n+\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ and let $n \to \infty$ you get $1$.

Comment: I see. I have two queries then. Firstly, why would a mathematical software like WolframAlpha say that the limit exists then? Secondly, is there a general way/method for me to ensure that I have covered all possible cases when I test "any line and curve"? I mean, I thought I had covered all cases but clearly not.

Comment: Several errors in WolframAlpha have been pointed pointed out on this site.  There is no general thumb rule for proving that multivariable limits do not exist. You have to  do it buy trial and error. @Meng

Comment: Okay! And what about dealing with absolute values? For example, if we have $\lvert x \rvert$ and $\lvert y \rvert$ when evaluating these limits at the origin, do the absolute value signs make a difference? I am thinking they do not since we are substituting $0$.

Comment: They can make a difference. A limit involving $x-y$ may differ from one involving $|x|-y$. @Meng

Comment: I made another post regarding evaluating a limit with absolute values [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4553982/how-to-deal-with-absolute-values-in-multi-variable-limits). Would you mind taking a look if you have the time? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your "the limit along any line and curve through the origin is 0 which is true in this case" was wrong: take the curve $x=y+y^3.$