# How to deal with absolute values in multi-variable limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

**Question**

Compute the limit $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {(x+y)^2}{3 \lvert{x}\lvert + \lvert {y} \lvert}.$$

**Edited Working**

My original answer revolved around considering different paths and I was not really getting anywhere. I have since been given some hints to use the squeeze theorem instead and have come up with the following:

$$\frac{x+y}{3} 
= \frac{(x+y)^2}{3(x+y)}
\leq \frac{(x +y)^2}{3 \lvert x \lvert + \lvert y \lvert} 
\leq \frac{(\lvert x \lvert  + \lvert y \lvert )^2}{\lvert x \lvert + \lvert y \lvert}
= \lvert x \lvert + \lvert y \lvert$$

Now, by the squeeze theorem, since $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \lvert x \lvert + \lvert y \lvert = 0$$ and $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {x + y }{3} = 0,$$ so $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {(x+y)^2}{3 \lvert{x}\lvert + \lvert {y} \lvert} = 0.$$

As I have only just covered multi-variable calculus, I am wondering whether my approach and answer is correct.

Comment: The problem is that, even if the function converges on every line $y=mx$, and to the same value $0$, it doesn't need to converge in general. Consider the function (in polar coordinates) $f(\rho, \theta)=\begin{cases}1&\rho>\theta>0\\0&\rho\le\theta, \theta>0\\0&\theta = 0\end{cases}$ for $0\le\theta\lt 2\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:
$$
\frac{(x+y)^2}{3|x| + |y|} \le \frac{(x + y)^2}{|x| + |y|} \le \frac{x^2}{|x| + |y|} + \frac{2|xy|}{|x| + |y|} + \frac{y^2}{|x| + |y|} \le
$$
$$
\le \frac{x^2}{|x|} + 2\frac{|xy|}{|y|} + \frac{y^2}{|y|}.
$$
Of course, cases where $x$ or $y$ are equal to $0$ can be handled separately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mean to say that my approach is correct so far, in the sense that the limit does exist and I should proceed with an epsilon-delta proof?

Comment: $\frac{(x+y)^2}{3|x| + |y|} \leq \frac{(x + y)^2}{|x| + |y|} \leq \frac{(|x| + |y|)^2}{|x|+|y|} = |x| + |y|$ would probably be faster/simpler.

Comment: @Meng Indeed, limit exists, equal to 0. No need for epsilon-delta, sinse you can say that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{(x + y)^2}{3|x| + |y|} \le \lim_{x \to 0} |x| + \lim_{y \to 0} |y|$ as Bruno B suggested and you can you use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: I see! I have since edited my answer to use the squeeze theorem instead. Would you be so kind as to help me review it and let me know whether my proof is valid?